# gcc stack optimization?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, disassembly

I just wrote a code sample in C and tried disassembling it. Following is the code sample.

```
void start() {
    char phone[100];
    strcmp(phone, "12312312313");

    char name[100];
    strcmp(name, "eQuiNoX");

    char contact[100];
    strcmp(contact, "PM twitter.com/eQuiNoX__");
}
```

When I disassemble the start function I get the following:-

```
08048414 <start>:
 8048414: 55                    push   ebp
 8048415: 89 e5                 mov    ebp,esp
 8048417: 81 ec 58 01 00 00     sub    esp,0x158
 804841d: c9                    leave  
 804841e: c3                    ret
```

1. I have not enabled any kind of optimization. Could someone explain why I get `158` subtracted from esp rather than assembly code which pushes values onto the stack and calls the `strcmp` method? Is it because it does not depend on any user input?
2. Also, is there any way I could generate the `extended assembly`(im not sure if thats the right term, i just wish to see the assembly code for pushing values onto the stack and the calling of the strcmp function). Is there any way I could do that?
3. Is this kind of behavior specific to processor architectures or gcc versions or both?

Comment: Well, with optimizations this kind of disasm would make sense, but without optimizations it looks strange. Are you sure you have no optimizations?

Comment: Anyway, try using the results of strcmp() and initializing those array

Comment: Did you explicitly pass -O0? Did you pass -fno-builtin?

Comment: @Joshua No, i hadnt passed any of those parameters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, `strcmp` is a standard library function, so gcc is free to have special knowledge about how it works. In fact, it does; it'll seldom generate a library call. You can try `-fno-builtin` to disable.

Second, you're comparing to unitialized values. This is, I believe undefined behavior. So the compiler may do anything it pleases, including producing random code.

You can try the `-S` option to gcc get more detailed disassembly (or, rather, lack of assembly); alternatively, if you compile with `-g` (debugging), `objdump -S` will display the source along with the assembled code.

Here is an example I compiled with `gcc -fno-builtin -g -O0 test.c -c` and then dumped with `objdump -S test.o`:

```
test.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
#include <string.h>

int main() {
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
    const char foo[] = "foo";
   8:   8b 05 00 00 00 00       mov    0x0(%rip),%eax        # e <main+0xe>
   e:   89 45 f0                mov    %eax,-0x10(%rbp)
    return strcmp(foo, "bar");
  11:   48 8d 45 f0             lea    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
  15:   be 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%esi
  1a:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  1d:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  22 <main+0x22>
}
  22:   c9                      leaveq 
  23:   c3                      retq
```

Comment: On my MinGW 4.5.1 test, `-fno-builtin -O0`  doesn't seem to force gcc to make a call to `strcmp()`.  I wonder why.

Comment: @Michael Burr: Not sure, you could try turning off a bunch of dead-code elimination options explicitly. It's also possible that your string.h does something funny for strcmp, you may want to check the -E output to see.

Comment: the only thing I see about `strcmp()` (other than the calls) in the -E output is `int __attribute__((__cdecl__)) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__)) strcmp (const char*, const char*) __attribute__ ((__pure__));`. Anyway, this was just idle curiosity - certainly there's no need to spend any cycles on this...

Comment: @Micheal, without spending too much cycles, I think the `__pure__` tells the compiler that the function has no effect but by its return value. Because the code doesn't use that, the call is just thrown away.

Comment: Add the `-r` option to `objdump` for relocations. Otherwise `call` instructions will appear very misleading.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the `sub esp,0x158` instruction, rather than generate a boatload of `push` operations (which involve copying the operand to the stack too, not just reserving space), typically the compiler will just reserve enough space for all local variables by moving the stack pointer just once.  That's what this instruction is doing.  `0x158` is 344 in decimal, so it's reserving 300 bytes for the arrays and probably some extra space for compiler generated structures (or maybe to put the strcmp operands on the stack too).

Answer (score 4):

1. Because your code has no effect in the program execution. All variables are used in function calls whose return values are discarded, thus the compiler tagged it as unused code, and felt it should remove. If you want to keep the unused code, be sure you're not using any optimisations - compile with `-O0`.
2. See my point above.
3. I suspect most compilers would perform this optimisation, independent of architecture.

Comment: It could be done only for functions that are known to be `pure`.

Comment: @ruslik: as is the case of the presented function. Nevertheless, that's the correct terminology.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it really was optimized. You can try compiling with -O0 flag to ensure that no optimization is made (however I'm not sure it will work).

Or you can just return cmp results from the start function to show the compiler that you really use them:

```
int start() {
    char phone[] = "43423432";
    return strcmp(phone, "12312312313");
}
```