# Understanding stack in linux

Tags: c, linux, assembly, disassembly

I have a small (and vulnerable) C sample:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buff[100];

    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Syntax: %s <input string>\n", argv[0]);
        exit (0);
    }

    strcpy(buff, argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with:

```
gcc -o basic_overflow basic_overflow.c -fno-stack-protector -fno-builtin
```

When I open this program with gdb, disassembly looks like this:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x08048424 <+0>: push   ebp
   0x08048425 <+1>: mov    ebp,esp
   0x08048427 <+3>: and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x0804842a <+6>: add    esp,0xffffff80
...
```

Setting a breakpoint in main (after the prologue). Since we have a local buffer I would expect my stackframe to be 100 bytes in size. However when I do $ebp-$esp, I can see that the result is actually 136.

Plattform: `Linux user-VirtualBox 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:50 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux`

Compiler: `gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2`
Debugger: `GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.2-1ubuntu11) 7.2`
What did I get wrong?

Comment: What platform are you on? What are your compilation options? Which compiler version? It's difficult to answer a question about low-level details without knowing the above facts.

Comment: what does the disassembly show?

Comment: doesn't gcc put argc and argv on the stack as well?

Comment: Since they are params to main I guess i does. But shouldn't those be at a positive displacement from ebp and not count into the size of the frame?

Comment: So we are compiling without optimizations, and wonder why the code isn't very good. We shouldn't do that!

Comment: possible duplicate of [gcc stack optimization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694280/gcc-stack-optimization)

Comment: We are trying to learn buffer overflows and assembly. Therfore we don't want the complier to do anthing fancy to optimize the binary.

Comment: But then you shouldn't wonder why the generated code isn't optimized, like allocating the minimum amount of space needed.

Comment: I reckoned that that was the default. Since it didn't occur to me why the compiler would reserve more space. The size of buff is known at compile-time after all.

Comment: @BoPersson, flawed thinking; `-O` may actually **increase** the frame size because of inlining coalescing multiple frames.

Answer (score 4):

It's not just the size of the local variables - generally speaking there is the padding to the size specified by the platform ABI, clobbered registers, `alloca()` area... - check for example [this nice picture](http://docs.huihoo.com/embedded-devkit/1.0/getting-started-guide/gstools.html#11645)

Comment: In your case e.g. the outgoing parameters to `printf` are reserved upfront on the stack (`ebp-8ch`, `ebp-90h`) and their values are `mov`ed into the reserved slots instead of being `push`ed just before the call (set **`-mno-accumulate-outgoing-args`** to disable). Also, copies of `argc` (`ebp-78h`) and `argv` (`ebp-68h`) with padding are created on the stack (set **`-mpreferred-stack-boundary=2`** to disable.)  Once both options above are provided, only `64h` is subtracted from `esp` as desired.